# Screen recording wayland 22.04

Tags: command-line, 22.04, wayland

Currently trying to find a screen recorder (full screen) that can be activated on startup - not a Ubuntu expert so any assistance / direction would be appreciated.

Happy to consider commercial paid application if needed as so far have had very little success

Comment: Please edit your questions and add details which software you already tried but probably didn't give the desired results.